# How can I solve data range error into google sheets with appscript

Tags: javascript, range

I have a google app script that allows me to retrieve data via a public API and a fetch. So far so good. I initialized a table in order to push the data into it, then I call a function that will send the data to a column of my google sheets table. My first function fills the array with a "while" loop, when the length of the array reaches 12, my "pushDatasToSheet" function launches but I have an error, the console tells me that my data range is at 1 and therefore does not correspond not in range of my selected cells. What is funny is that my table does indeed indicate a length of 12 when executing my function sending data to the table and when I modify the range of my cells by putting only one , the console shows me 12 for my data range. I can't find where my mistake is coming from. thank you in advance for your help.
Here an image of the console error:

[error code in app script console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uT79.png)

And my code:

```js
const signsList = ["aries", "taurus", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "scorpio", "sagittarius", "capricorn", "aquarius", "pisces"];

var SHEET_NAME = "horoscope";

const options = {
  'method': 'post',
};

var rowDescription = [];

// Get horoscopes from API
function doPost(e) {
  signsList.forEach(sign => {
    while (rowDescription.length < 12) {
      var url = 'https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/?sign=' + sign + '&day=today';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var json = response.getContentText();
      var data = JSON.parse(json);

      rowDescription.push(data.description);
    }
    pushDatasToSheet();
  })

}

function pushDatasToSheet() {
  Logger.log(rowDescription.length);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var descriptionColumn = sheet.getRange('B2:B13');
  descriptionColumn.setValues([rowDescription]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved 
In case another person with the same problem happen, the array have to be a 2D array. And i have changed my while loop for a if statement.

Here the correction snippet:

```js
const signsList = ["aries", "taurus", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "scorpio", "sagittarius", "capricorn", "aquarius", "pisces"];

var SHEET_NAME = "horoscope";

const options = {
  'method': 'post',
};

var rowDescription = [];

// Get horoscopes from API

function doPost(e) {

  if (rowDescription.length < 12) {
    signsList.forEach(sign => {
      var url = 'https://aztro.sameerkumar.website/?sign=' + sign + '&day=today';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var json = response.getContentText();
      var data = JSON.parse(json);

      rowDescription.push([data.description]);
    })
  }
  pushDatasToSheet();
}

function pushDatasToSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    sheet.getRange('B2:B13').setValues(rowDescription);
};
```